# Cancan and using has_many relationships for :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan

A Book has_many Chapters. A User has_many Books.

I'm using devise and cancancan, and I want to allow a user to :create a chapter for any Book they own. My problem is, a Chapter does not belong to a Book until it exists so in ability.rb -

```
can [:read, :update, :destroy], Chapter do |chapter|
  chapter.book.user_id == user.id
end
```

is fine, but using this on :create throws a nil method, because until the object has been created, it does not have any properties. I've resorted to putting a check in the create action in the controller -

```
if @chapter.book.user == current_user && @chapter.save
```

...which is fine, but there's got to be a better way, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases you can use:

```
     # or just :manage
can [:read, :update, :destroy, :create], Chapter do |chapter| 
  chapter.new_record? || chapter.book.user_id == user.id
end
```

However, I would simplify it a bit:

```
can :manage, Chapter, book: { user_id: user.id }
```

Comment: Hi blelump - could you explain to me what's happening in your second code block? Does Rails know that the :book in the hash is the book the chapter belongs to?

Comment: Yep, it does. It is a common `cancancan` approach to define permissions only for particular resources. Look [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#user-content-hash-of-conditions) for an example. In short, use blocks only in the last resort, because it costs more (in sense of time). Instead, use hash which matches given permission associations. I know sometimes it is not so simple and block is your only choice, but it's a good practice to define contitions as a hash. PS. switch to `cancancan`, `cancan` is dead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really helpful. I am using cancancan, will amend the q accordingly. :)

Comment: I actually got an error when I came to implement it - that == shouldn't be there, and the first part of the hash should be a symbol I think - this is what worked for me `can :manage, Chapter, book: { user_id: user.id }`